# How to use single public IP to access multiple application servers in SAP?

Tags: port-forwarding, dmz, sap

### Scenario

I have:

- Wireless D-Link Router Connected to the Internet
- Two IBM-Lenovo Servers Connected( Wireless/Wired) to the Router

Two servers have IP addresses : 192.xxx.xxx.123 and 192.xxx.xxx.124

- Both the servers have been configured as SAP Application Servers and working fine but each time I want to use the server I need to change the IP address in DMZ option in the router
- One Public IP : 68.xxx.xxx.123

And,

- 68.xxx.xxx.123 can be accessed from anywhere in the world.
- I have setup DMZ and forwarded all the ports to the local IP of one of the server i.e. 192.xxx.xxx.123

### What i want to do?

- I don't want to use DMZ option if possible.
- Access both the servers, one at a time, using SAP GUI without the need of checking DMZ option

Answer (score 1):

You could put the servers on the inside and set up each one with a different external port forwarded to the correct internal ip:port.

Answer (score 0):

I would use NAT, find all the ports you need (hopefully just one) for your application and forward those ports to server 'A', then choose an alternate port(s) on the public interface for server 'B' and then route it to the correct port internally.  I know this can be done with pfSense, not sure about your D-Link Router.

Comment: I forwarded few ports but its not working. I forwarded 3200, 3240, 3275 ... and few other. Currently I am using my routers DMZ option to forward all the ports to one of my server. I tried forwarding some ports but not working.

Comment: Looks like there are a lot of ports and port ranges for SAP.  http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-17124  Good luck with that.